# Ineffective TCP SYN Flood from Meta Sploit Framework

Tags: apache, security, ubuntu, tcp, denial-of-service

I want my Apache 2 web Server to have a Denial of Service due to an TCP Syn Flood Attack.

I used Kali Linux in Combination with the MSF to take my web server down.
But my web server doesn't seem to care about that.

I am using an Apache 2 on Ubuntu 14.04 with the IP 192.168.1.254 and my attacker is a Kali Linux with the IP 192.168.1.1.

I tracked the network traffic with Wireshark and everything is fine the syn packets arrive at my web server (tons of packages).

My Network is completely virtual and exists only on my ESX Server. Could that be the problem ?

I also disabled the syn cookies on my Ubuntu machine.

Why won't my web server die? Even the response time is not affected.

Comment: Use `netstat` on your server to count the number of sockets in the `SYN_RCVD` state. Each one of these costs a file handle and a socket. Your server should start to struggle when either the max file handle `ulimit` is hit or all ports in the `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range` are taken, whichever comes first. nb. The IP local port range is _per network interface_ and will affect all processes using that interface.

Comment: Netstat shows me only about 20-30 connections although millions of packets are being received according to wireshark.

Comment: OK, so do `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_max_syn_backlog` to see how many incomplete connections are permitted by your Linux installation.

Comment: cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_max_syn_backlog => 128.Now i discovered a way to take my webserver down. I have to spoof my Source ip adress then the server goes down. But i am wondering where is the synflood detection mechanism of ubuntu which says . "Hey , this Ip Adress is performing an Attack , lets drop these packets".

Comment: It could be an `iptables` rule. You could temporarily [turn off iptables](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/turn-on-turn-off-firewall-in-linux) to see if that's your issue. Don't forget to turn it back on again :)

Answer (score 1):

Your host operating system is probably ignoring the SYN flood after a while, non-malicious connections are still completed in a timely manner and passed down to the HTTP server.

Comment: Yes that's true netstat only lists about 20 SYN_RECV Connections from my attacker IP. But how do i stop that , he should accept all Packets ? I want him to die.